# CakePHP console returns some code

Tags: php, bash, cakephp, console

So I was following the tutorial from CakePHP docs and when I tried using php bin/cake bake (on Windows) instead of baking it returned some license and a bunch of code that looks like a part of file.
Has anyone ever encountered such a problem before?

[image: CakePHP console]

Comment: Do not use php to run the console, it will do that on its own.

Comment: The problem was actually with the console. I switched from cmder to git bash and it works and indeed deos not requre the php command (cmder did). I suppose cmder has an option somewhere to try and open the contents of a file instead of trating it as a console.

Comment: Don't use ```php bin/cake ... ``` just ```bin/bake ..```